# Getting elements from a list by an index list

Tags: list, haskell

I have two lists in Haskell.

Original list containing string values:

```
["Hello", "HELLO", "", "WORLD", "xxx", "world"]
```

Index list containing integer values where the strings are all upper case in the original list:

```
[1,3]
```

I incremented all the values in the index list with a function I created and make `index2` list, overall it looks like this:

My code:

```
import Data.List 
import Data.Char 
import Data.Maybe 

main = do 
    contents <- readFile "h.txt" 
    let original = lines (contents) 
    let allUpper = lines (map toUpper contents) 
    let onlyUpper = filter(/="") (intersect original allUpper) 
    let upperIndex = findIndices ('elem' onlyUpper) original 
    let index2 = (map increment upperIndex) 
    print index2 

increment :: Int -> Int 
increment x = x+1
```

I have managed to came this far with the help of yours. However, since I am a beginner I do not seem to understand how iteration over lists works.

The thing I want to accomplish is to check whether the corresponding index values (in `index2`) are empty or not in the original list, if they are empty, I want to remove them in `index2`.

Comment: Thank you to one who gives minus to my questions (!)

Comment: @Kevin Guan , Thanks!

Comment: That is a screenshot.

Comment: The site did not accept it. So, I had to make a screen shot. Sorry.

Comment: *How the site didn't accept it?* Because you can't keep the right format?

Comment: Lol. Can we please keep focusing on the problem :) Thanks

Comment: Well, without the code we can't help you because we can't copy-paste your code and run or debug it. I think nobody'd like type your code instead of just Ctrl+C. So please **post your code instead of just an image** next time. However this time you don't need do that, *see my powerful edit!*

Comment: @Kevin Guan, Thanks, you are awesome Sir!!! :)

Comment: It seems you want your indices to "skip" a line if that line is empty. If so, simply filter the lines before indexing: `let original = filter (not.null) . lines$ contents`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Filtering empty elements

> The thing I want to accomplish is to check whether the corresponding
>   index values (in index2) are empty or not in the original list, if
>   they are empty, I want to remove them in index2.

The code already filters out empty elements! Look at the following line:

```
let onlyUpper = filter(/="") (intersect original allUpper)
```

This line does two things:

- it keeps only elements which are constituted only with uppercase letters(`intersect original allUpper`),
- it filters out empty elements (`filter(/="")`).

If by empty elements you mean strings which contains only space characters or nothing, you can use instead:

```
filter (all isSpace)
```

## Iterating over lists

> I do not seem to understand how iteration over lists works.

In Haskell, lists are single chained lists: each element contains a value and a reference to the next value.

Therefore lists are not indexed: the `!!` operator have to go through each element to access a specific element making lists completely inefficient when dealing with direct access.

When you’re submitting a list to a function, you simply give it the first element.

With these considerations, when you work on lists, you have to avoid accessing elements via their index.

The idea is to create functions which do their job on simple values and mapping them to list of elements. Take a look at the `toUpper` function:

```
toUpper :: Char -> Char
```

It takes a `Char` and returns its uppercased version (also a `Char`).

Haskell does not have a `toUpper` function which works on `String`, you have to use something like `map` or `<$>` to apply `toUpper` to a list of char (a `String`):

```
map toUpper "ab" -- "AB"
toUpper <$> "ab" -- "AB"
```

The idea is to have functions which does only one specific thing. Upercasing and iterating over a list are two different things. Does the `toUpper` function need to know the index of the element it will uppercase? No!

## Iterating over a list with index

You may ask: but what if my function REALLY need to consider the index of the elements? (ie: for filtering out even or odd elements).

You have two way of considering it:

- a `List` is not the type you need to work with. Maybe Data.Map, Data.IntMap or Data.Vector are better suited for the task (see these modules for more information),
- you need to use an intermediate type which will hold the index.

For example:

```
let string = "abcde"
let indexedString = zip [1..] string

print indexedString -- [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b), (3, 'c), (4, 'd), (5, 'e)]
```

Note that this also solves your need of an increment function since the index is started at whatever value you want.

To go back to the original string, you write:

```
map snd indexedString -- "abcde"
```

You need to use the `fst` and `snd` functions to work with the intermediate type, or to use pattern matching:

```
filter (\x -> snd x == 'b') indexedString -- [(2, 'b')]
map (\(i,s) -> (i, toUpper s)) indexedString -- [(1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C'),(4,'D'),(5,'E')]
```

Taking the index into account:

```
let string = "abcde"
    indexedString = zip [1..] string

    upperEven (i, c) | even i = (i, toUpper c)
                     | otherwise = (i, c)

print $ map upperEven indexedString -- [(1,'a'),(2,'B'),(3,'c'),(4,'D'),(5,'e')]
print $ map snd $ map upperEven indexedString -- "aBcDe"
```

## Notes

The `increment` function already exists in Haskell, it’s called `succ` (it is also a more generic function which works on every types supporting the `Enum` class like Int, Char…)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `words :: String -> [String]` on the contents you get from a file? Using `lines :: String -> [String]` would be an alternative if you had one word per line.

Then if i get your problem right, you could write the following to solve your problem:

```
import Data.List (findIndices)
import Data.Char (isUpper)

allUpperOneBasedIndices :: String -> [Int]
allUpperOneBasedIndices = map succ . findIndices (all isUpper) . words
```